# Flutter changeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

is there a solution to put changeNotifierProvider under a spécifications tree because i think i'ts wastfull to put it above in the main while i want is just in some widget?

I want to able to use changenotifier provider under the main widget

Comment: Yes you can do that, `ChangeNotifierProvider(create: create,..)` It would be nice if you include sample widget that you are trying to overcome

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).